# Brodcast a message to all servers the bot is in but not in the rules channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have looked and I have found out how to get a message to broadcast to all servers but it would annoy server owners to have bot announcements in rules. What would be the best way to modify this code to send to all servers but not their rules channel?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in client.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
            try:
                await channel.send(msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

If all the rules channels are named `rules` in the servers your bot is in, you can simply add an if-check to avoid sending messages to that channel.

---

### Example

```py
for channel in server.text_channels:
    if channel.name == "rules":
        continue
```

### Notes

- The channel will be skipped only if it's named `rules`.
- This will send your message in ALL other channels except rules, do you really want to do that? (can be considered spam).